# Is there a function in matlab to evaluate homogeneity and completeness of a clustering solution?

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, performance-testing

I'm working on a clustering problem and I want to evaluate the performance. Given a data set of samples and a testing set containing the truth class assignments of the samples. Is there a function in matlab to evaluate homogeneity and completeness? homogeneity: each cluster contains only members of a single class. completeness: all members of a given class are assigned to the same cluster.

Comment: I doubt there's a built-in function specifically for this, because all you're doing is counting the number of members that match certain criteria. For more specific answers you'll need to include at least the structure of your classifier output and preferably your attempt at the evaluation code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Almost every "external" cluster evaluation method is based on these concepts. Theynare maybe not exactly what you described - because they attempt to solve the problem that clusters and classes usually do not align well. If matlab is any good for clustering (ok, it is not very common anymore...), it ought to have several of such measures.